# How to Remove the yellow bar notification for specific document library in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, document-library, notifications, hide-elements

I need to remove the SharePoint yellow bar notification message for specific document library using C#. I know we can achieve by using CSS as mentioned [here](https://krishnanandula.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/hide-yellow-status-bar-sharepoint-2010/)

I am wondering is there has any way to achieve this by disabling some property using c# or PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you have described as "yellow bar notification" is called `Status bar`

The `Status bar` can't be disabled or enabled using C# or Powershell Because it's not a Server Side property, it's JS `SP.UI.Status` class that defined in `SP.Js` / `SP.Debug.Js`

---

**The alternative solutions to remove/disable the `Status bar`:**

1. **Using JS**

   - Remove a specific Status Bar

     ```
      SP.UI.Status.removeStatus(StatusBarID);
     ```
   - Remove all Status Bar

     ```
      SP.UI.Status.removeAllStatus(true);
     ```
2. **Using CSS**

   ```
   #StatusBarID
    {
      display:none !important
    }
   ```

Check also [How to use Status Bar in SharePoint 2010?](http://geekswithblogs.net/venkatx5/archive/2010/11/18/how-to-use-status-bar-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)